# MySQL Complex Query (group by)

Tags: mysql

Below is my query:

```
SELECT date, eventype, count(*) AS count 
FROM vpnhistory WHERE partnername   REGEXP 'CESAR'
GROUP BY (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)) DIV 600;
```

What I'm getting:

```
+---------------------+--------------+---------+
| date                | eventype     | counter |
+---------------------+--------------+---------+
| 2016-09-30 12:42:41 | blocked      |       4 |
| 2016-10-03 10:55:55 | blocked      |       1 |
| 2016-10-03 13:43:01 | blocked      |       1 |
| 2016-10-04 15:17:19 | blocked      |       2 |
| 2016-10-04 15:21:03 | blocked      |       3 |
```

This is the total eventype that the CESAR partnername has received.

My `SELECT * FROM vpnhistory` is:

```
+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+
| vpnname              | date                | eventype     | partnername |
+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+
| treinamento-12345678 | 2016-09-30 12:42:41 | blocked      | CESAR       |
| treinamento-45263748 | 2016-09-30 12:43:53 | unlock       | CESAR       |
| treinamento-92837465 | 2016-09-30 12:46:50 | unlock       | CESAR       |
| treinamento-92837465 | 2016-09-30 12:46:50 | unlock       | CESAR       |
| treinamento-92837465 | 2016-09-30 12:46:50 | unlock       | CESAR       |
+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

What I need for example:

```
How many eventype treinamento-92837465 exists? (inside partnername CESAR)
How many eventype treinamento-12345678 exists? (inside partnername CESAR)
```

Comment: Provide sample data and expected data.

Comment: Just add eventtype field to the group by clause.

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, eventtype, count(*)
FROM vpnhistory WHERE partnername   REGEXP 'CESAR'
GROUP BY date, eventtype
```

Is that what you want? I didn't understand your first group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need add field used for grouping to SELECT:

```
SELECT 
  date,
  eventype,
  count(*) AS count,
  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)) DIV 600 AS group_field
FROM vpnhistory 
WHERE partnername   REGEXP 'CESAR'
GROUP BY group_field;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
SELECT vpnname, date, eventype, count(*) AS counter
FROM vpnhistory 
WHERE partnername REGEXP 'CESAR'
GROUP BY (vpnname), (eventype), ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)) DIV 600);

+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------+
| vpnname                                    | date                | eventype     | counter |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------+
| vpn-1234                                   | 2016-12-02 08:36:53 | blocked      |       1 |
| vpn-1234                                   | 2016-12-02 08:36:49 | unlocked     |       1 |
| vpn-1823781289371289378192983              | 2016-10-13 16:20:40 | blocked      |       1 |
| vpn-2983494879234789327233                 | 2016-10-19 09:27:13 | blocked      |       1 |
| vpn-2983494879234789327233                 | 2016-10-19 11:56:14 | unblocked    |       1 |
| vpn-9123898293383838                       | 2016-10-03 10:55:55 | blocked      |       1 |
```